# Communicating with the outside world from within an atomic database transaction

Tags: python, mysql, django, transactions, atomic

I am implementing an import tool (Django 1.6) that takes a potentially very large CSV file, validates it and depending on user confirmation imports it or not. Given the potential large filesize, the processing of the file is done via flowy (a python wrapper over Amazon's SWF). Each import job is saved in a table in the DB and the workflow, which is quite simple and consists of only one activity, basically calls a method that runs the import and saves all necessary information about the processing of the file in the job's record in the database.

The tricky thing is: We now have to make this import atomic. Either all records are saved or none. But one of the things saved in the import table is the progress of the import, which is calculated based on the position of the file reader:

```
progress = (raw_data.tell() * 100.0) / filesize
```

And this progress is used by an AJAX progressbar widget in the client side. So simply adding `@transaction.atomic` to the method that loops through the file and imports the rows is not a solution, because the progress will only be saved on commit.

The CSV files only contain one type of record and affect a single table. If I could somehow do a transaction only on this table, leaving the job table free for me to update the progress column, it would be ideal. But from what I've found so far it seems impossible. The only solution I could think of so far is opening a new thread and a new database connection inside it every time I need to update the progress. But I keep wondering… will this even work? Isn't there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple approach would be to use the `READ UNCOMMITTED` transaction isolation level. That *could* allow dirty reads, which would allow your other processes to see the progress even though the transaction hasn't been committed. However, whether this works or not will be database-dependent. (I'm not familiar with MySQL, but this wouldn't work in PostgreSQL because `READ UNCOMMITTED` works the same way as `READ COMMITTED`.)

Regarding your proposed solution, you don't necessarily need a new thread, you really just need a fresh connection to the database. One way to do that in Django might be to take advantage of the [multiple database support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/). I'm imagining something like this:

1. As described in the documentation, add a new entry to `DATABASES` with a different name, but the same setup as `default`. From Django's perspective we are using multiple databases, even though we in fact just want to get multiple connections to the same database.
2. When it's time to update the progress, do something like:

   ```
   JobData.objects.using('second_db').filter(id=5).update(progress=0.5)
   ```

   That should take place in its own autocommitted transaction, allowing the progress to be seen by your web server.

Now, does this work? I honestly don't know, I've never tried anything like it!

Comment: Hi Kevin, in the meantime, while reading about DB management in Django, I also had the idea of using a second alias with the same data. And it does work! I just call the transaction without the `using` parameter, which presumably creates a transaction in the default DB, then I use the normal interface for the Membership model (e.g. `Membership.objects.create(...)`) and add `using` when interacting with the ImportJob object (as in your example). An exception in the middle of the process results in a rollback with no data imported, and the progress bar works :)

Comment: @Ariel: Great, glad to hear it.